# Preview image on page before uploading it works in all browsers but IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that will show the image you're about to upload before clicking submit.  It merely shows the image on the page with you choose a file.  This works in all browsers but IE.  It's a pretty simple javascript function.  Any ideas why this wouldn't render in IE?  Thank you.

Here's the Javascript in the head of the page:

```
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(75)
                    .height(75);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

This is the HTML for the empty image.  After choosing a file it will be displayed in the img id="blah".  This renderes properly in all browsers but IE.

```
<div id="question_submit_outside_holder">
    <input type="submit" name="question_reply_upload_image" id="questions_place_inline_image_form_submit_one" value="Place image" />
</div>

<div id="questions_form_image_upload_image_holder">
    <img id="blah" src="" /> <!-- img should be displayed here -->
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

This is how I append images to the post.  It displays in all browsers but IE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    image = '<img src="http://forum.site.com/.../<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>/question_reply_images/<?php echo $image_name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" />';
    document.getElementById('editor1').innerHTML += image;
    window.location = '#reply_textbox';
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does not work in IE!
IE9 and below does not support FileReader API, which enables thumbnail preview in the code you posted.

*Good news: IE10 does support FileReader API.*
http://caniuse.com/filereader

Comment: Thanks!  Answers that...  Does this apply to appending images to textareas?  I'm using a WYSYWIG editor.  When the user uploades a file I append the image to the post.  However, the image is not displayed in IE.

Comment: Its not displayed, because IE cannot read it. So, yes - you will not be able to add image to textarea, as well.

Comment: Is there a hack or work around for appending images to a post?  This basically illegitimizes the whole set up I've made for writing posts.

Comment: See the update I made in the question.  That is how I append images in the post.

Comment: you can _try_ Flash or Silverlight polyfills (like this: https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader), but proceed at your own risk. There _might_ be bugs.

Comment: Cool I'll try that.  Did you see how I'm appending the image?  Any reason why that wouldn't work in IE.  All I'm using is the "+=" operator in javascript.